# CodeCahe is full java7

Tags: java

I am getting below error when we compile java classed

using java version
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

I have tried to increase the reservedcodeCachesize to 80M also not working. Any suggestions on this would be really helpful?

```
 [exec] Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled.
 [exec] Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
 [exec] Code Cache  [0xf8c00000, 0xf8e60000, 0xfdc00000)
 [exec]  total_blobs=1129 nmethods=986 adapters=72 free_code_cache=79503Kb largest_free_block=81411200
 [exec] #
 [exec] # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
 [exec] # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 4092 bytes for char in /export/HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u11-2-build-solaris-sparc-product/jdk7u11/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/stack.inline.hpp
 [exec] # An error report file with more information is saved as:

 [exec] Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled.
 [exec] Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
 [exec] Code Cache  [0xf8c00000, 0xf8e60000, 0xfdc00000)
 [exec]  total_blobs=1140 nmethods=997 adapters=72 free_code_cache=79497Kb largest_free_block=81405696
 [exec] Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled.
 [exec] Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
 [exec] Code Cache  [0xf8c00000, 0xf8e60000, 0xfdc00000)
 [exec]  total_blobs=1144 nmethods=1000 adapters=72 free_code_cache=79495Kb largest_free_block=81403392
 [exec] #
 [exec] # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
 [exec] # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 4092 bytes for char in /export/HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u11-2-build-solaris-sparc-product/jdk7u11/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/stack.inline.hpp
 [exec] # An error report file with more information is saved as:
 [exec] # /vobs/wran_cm/wran_cm_mom/src/com/ericsson/nms/umts/ranos/wranmom/tmp/momjenkins/O10/mom/xml_4-27-15-52-24/output_jar/hs_err_pid23237.log
 [exec] Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled.
 [exec] Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
 [exec] Code Cache  [0xf8c00000, 0xf8e58000, 0xfdc00000)
 [exec]  total_blobs=1147 nmethods=1005 adapters=72 free_code_cache=79520Kb largest_free_block=81428992
 [exec] #
 [exec] # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
 [exec] # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate #
 [exec] # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
 [exec] # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 8192 bytes for card table expansion
 [exec] # An error report file with more information is saved as:
 [exec] # 
 [exec] #
 [exec] # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
 [exec] # Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 4092 bytes for char in /export/HUDSON/workspace/jdk7u11-2-build-solaris-sparc-product/jdk7u11/hotspot/src/share/vm/utilities/stack.inline.hpp
 [exec] # An error report file with more information is saved as:
 [exec] #
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with increasing it to 384m can you also please try enabling code-cache flushing it, should work.

```
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=384m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
```